# Diseño de relación uno a muchos

Tags: sql, sql-server

En mi diseño de la base de datos estoy enfrentado el siguiente caso:

Tengo `equipos` en una tabla los cuales pueden asignarse a `empleados` o `vehiculos`, los cuales están en sus respectivas tablas.

La relación que debo hacer es uno a muchos, mi duda en el diseño es si debo crear una tabla, por ejemplo `equipos_asignados` con los campos: `id_equipo`,`id_empleado`,`id_vehiculo` y si asigno un equipo a un empleado dejar `null` el campo `id_vehiculo` y si asigno un equipo a un `vehiculo` dejar `null` el campo `id_empleado`.

Quiero saber si eso es aceptado en el diseño o si hay una mejor solución para ese tipo de casos.

> Actualización:

Las reglas del negocio son así:

- Cada equipo en la tabla `equipos` sólo puede asignarse una vez, ya sea a un empleado o a un vehículo, esto es así porque el código de ese equipo se usa para etiquetar el equipo real al que representa.
- A cada uno de los equipos se les hacen pruebas en laboratorio, se les hace mantenimiento y otros procesos en los cuales se usa el código del equipo.

Ahora el problema está en como asignar esos equipos ya sea a clientes o vehículos y de ahí sale mi propuesta de solución.

Comment: Creo que sería muy buena idea para empezar a ayudarte, conocer la regla de negocio la cual tratas de solucionar con tu diseño, de ese modo se puede tener una respuesta mas certera sobre lo que tratas de almacenar y si tu propuesta es atinada o no.

Comment: ya actualicé la consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que la relación de equipos con la demás entidades es **uno a uno** es mejor crear llaves foráneas en la tabla equipos, así te evitas la complejidad adicional.

Y con respecto a la mala práctica de diseño no lo es, en lo que respecta a normalización ya que no estás creando datos repetidos.

Answer (score 3):

Yo haría entonces una tabla equipo_asignado, la cual sea provista de las siguientes columnas:

```
CREATE TABLE equipo_prestamo(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  empleado_id INT NULL,
  auto_id INT NULL,
  equipo_id INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_equipos_prestamo_autos FOREIGN KEY(auto_id) REFERENCES autos(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_equipos_prestamo_equipo FOREIGN KEY(equipo_id) REFERENCES equipos(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_equipos_prestamo_empleados FOREIGN KEY(empleado_id) REFERENCES empleados(id),
  statusPrestamos TINYINT
);
```

**Explicación**

- Conjuntamos los `id` de las tres tablas: `empleado`, `auto`, `equipo` en una sola tabla que llamaremos `equipo_prestamo`.
- Para que no se pueda regitrar mas de una vez un equipo a un usuario y luego a un auto, lo cual podemos subsanar con una columna `estatusPrestamo` la cual mediante programación será modificada pasando de 1(prestamo) a 0(no prestamo) y hasta que ese estado no cambie no se puede prestar un equipo a cualquiera de las otras 2 entidades.

> La anterior propuesta se hace pensando que en una única tabla conjuntando dichos datos se puede controlar y administrar para evitar prestar algo que ya se encuentra en préstamo, lo cual se haría difícil si registramos el id del equipo dentro de cada tabla por separado (es decir empleado o vehiculo).

Comment: Pero no sería un error de diseño que por cada registro queden dos campos de id nulos?

Comment: @crrlos Como propuesta de solución no lo creo, sin embargo válido tu duda y que alguien con más experiencia nos pueda responder